# Could not deduce template argument for T[]

Tags: c++

Now I'm getting another error.

```
error C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier
```

I know that for `temp` I need to declare the type of the array like `int temp[]`,
but what if I don't know what it is?
It could be `int` or `string` or `double`.
How can I create a temp array without specifying its type?

I added my Mergesort function.

Here is my code:

```
template<class T>
void Mergesort(T& a, int first, int last);
template<class T>
void Merge(T& a, int first, int last);    

int main()  
{
    int num;
    cout << "How many words? ";
    cin >> num;
    Array<string> b(num);
    cout << "Enter the " << num << " words below:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<num ; i++)
        cin >> b[i];
    cout << "\nThank you!!\n";

    // Copy the original array and sort it using Quicksort
    Array<string> bq(b);
    Quicksort(bq, 0, num-1);
    cout << "\nElements sorted using quicksort:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<num ; i++)  
        cout << bq[i]<< " ";
    cout << "\n";

    Array<string> bm(b);
    Mergesort(bm, 0, num-1);
    cout << "\nElements sorted using mergesort:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<num ; i++)  
    cout << bm[i]<< " ";
    cout << "\n";
}

template<class T>
void Mergesort(T& a, int first, int last) 
{
    if (first < last) 
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        Mergesort(a, first, mid);
        Mergesort(a, mid+1, last);
        Merge(a, first, last);
    }
}

template<class T>
void Merge(T& a, int first, int last) 
{
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    int one = 0, two = first, three = mid + 1;

    while (two <= mid && three <= last) // Neither sublist is done
        if (a[two] < a[three])          // Value in first half is smaller
            temp[one++] = a[two++];
        else                            // Value in second half is smaller
            temp[one++] = a[three++];
    while (two <= mid)                  // Finish copying first half
        temp[one++] = a[two++];
    while (three <= last)               // Finish copying second half
        temp[one++] = a[three++];
    for (one = 0, two = first; two <= last; a[two++] = temp[one++]);
}
```

ARRAY.h

```
using namespace std;

template<class T> class Array 
{
public:
    Array(int s);
    Array(int l, int h);

    Array(const Array& other);
    ~Array();

    T& operator[](int index);
    const T& operator[](int index) const;

    int get_size() const {return arraySize;}

private:
    int low;
    int high;
    int arraySize; //size of array
    int offset; //to adjust back to an index of zero
    T *array_;

    void Copy(const Array&);
};
```

Comment: Not enough information. What's `bq` at the point of the call? The error message mentions `Array` identifier and there's no such identifier in the code. Post real code, not some useless sketch!

Comment: Agreed, the definition of bq is missing. If you provide that, we could answer your question.

Comment: The error is about the template parameter bq, yet you omit all information about it. More code please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T a[]` means you expect an array of `T` as the parameter type - but thats a C array, not a class type. Your class template `Array` is just that - a class template that only happens to provide convenience access to its contents via `operator[]()`.

To fix the first error change `Quicksort()`s signature to:

```
template<class T>
void Quicksort(T& a, int first, int last)
```

Then there is the problem that you use `T` for a local variable `pivot`. To do that generically with containers, it is more or less standard to provide a `typedef` named `value_type` for the contained types (the values) of the container:

```
template<class T>
class Array 
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    // ...
};
```

With that convention you can declare `pivot` as follows:

```
T::value_type pivot;
```

Comment: The function should take a reference : `T& a`, instead of copying the `Array` object.